# MVC Modal Window DataBinding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have an object of type

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Personel { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

where

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

on my main page I list all Customers as a summary

```
@model List<Customer>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer No</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th># of personel</th>
            <th># of addresses</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if(Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Customer c in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => c.Id)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => c.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("$ " + c.Personel.Count(), "Summary", "Customer", new { onclick = "ShowPersonelDetails(" + item.Id + ")" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("$ " + c.Addresses.Count(), "Summary", "Customer", new { onclick = "ShowAddressDetails(" + item.Id + ")" })</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and when I click either address count or personel count ı want to display a pop-up listing the appropriate items.

To list personel (as an example I have the following partial view)

```
<div id="personel-details" class="ui-modal-window" title="Personeldetails">
    <table class="popup-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Place of birth</th>
                <th>Date of birth</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

To make this window modal I use the following script on my main page

```
$(function () {
    $("#balance-details").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        dialogClass: 'no-close',
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "OK",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }],
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 300
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "puff",
            duration: 300
        }
    });
});
```

and to call the list I use the following code:

```
function ShowCurrentBalanceDetails(__id) {
    var _id = null;
    if (__id && $.isNumeric(__id)) {
        _id = parseInt(__id);
    }
    if (_id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetPersonelRecords",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                id: _id
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#personel-details").html(result);
                $("#personel-details").dialog("open");
            },
            error: function (x, t, m, b) {
                alert(x.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("Error!!!!");
    }
}
```

The point is I want to display the Personel property of class Customer in the modal window,

1. How should I set the partial view data in the main page
2. How should I set the data in the modal window.

I have tried to set the List as data to partial view but I can not set the item properties then.

How can I accomplish my task?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you have achieved and what you're trying to achieve? It's not entirely clear from my perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I set the partial view data in the main page

If your action `GetPersonelRecords` will return a `PartialView` already with data populated, you just **place the result** of the action **in modal**.

> How should I set the data in the modal window.

Because you populate the data in the `PartialView` returned by `GetPersonelRecords`, at response you will get *html* and you place the html in modal `$("#personel-details").html(result);`.

---

The `PartialView` (`_PersonelPartial.cshtml`) will look almost the same as main view.

```
@model List<Customer>
<table class="popup-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Place of birth</th>
            <th>Date of birth</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if(Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Customer c in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => c.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => c.Surname)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => c.BirthPlace)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => c.Birthday)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

In your main view add this html where we will `append` data from the result of the Action

```
<div id="personel-details" class="ui-modal-window" title="Personeldetails">

</div>
```

You action will return a `PartialView` (with html rendereder)

```
public ActionResult GetPersonelRecords(string id) 
{
    var personel = // get personel by personId
    return PartialView("_PersonelPartial", personel);
}
```

The javascript ajax call remains the same because will populate the modal with the `PartialView` on this line `$("#personel-details").html(result);` also you have to change `dataType: "html"` [to receive html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14678239/3790486)

Comment: It almost seems to work fine but I have a problem. Although the ActionResult returns correct values and the code is sucessfully called and the returning HTTP State is 200 (OK) somehow Ajax call falls to `error:` code block. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: @user4591106 i think you get the error because `dataType: "json"` and it have to be `dataType: "html"`, keep me updated with your progress.

Comment: That is correct. Thank you very much. Your answer was very correct and helpful.