# ASP.NET MVC dynamically bind editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates, dynamic-binding

Is it possible to dynamically add an Editor Template to my view, after a button is clicked, for example?

At the moment I'm doing this in my main view to bind a list of `ObjectA` objects to my model (inside a form):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ObjectA)
```

and in the Editor Template I'm binding the properties for `ObjectA`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ID)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.BoolA)
```

But if I don't want to always *load* this editor template, is there a way to bind it dynamically to the model, using JS?

It's because it makes an additional request to the Database which I can omit by allowing the user to choose whether or not to make the request.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with `EditorFor` on client because the razor is transformed in html on server side.

You can do this if you make use of `PartialView`, where you can include your `EditorFor`.

You make a [`ajax` call with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678187/jquery-ajax-send-json-and-return-html/14678239#14678239) for this `PartialView`, but in `axaj` call you have to specify the **id** to query that object inside action.

At the end you will append the result, html content, of the call in your page.

Comment: So you mean having a partial view in which I have EditorFor. Do you think doing this will bind to the model, however? Am I not going to have prefix problems?

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't bind to the model (obviously). I decided to add an extra boolean to my model which checks whether it should make the request or not so when the user clicks a button it refreshes the page with an updated model that decides whether or not to display more data based on the user's choice

Comment: @sparta223 You tried to make `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ObjectA)` or `@Html.EditorFor(x => x)` ?

Comment: I made a partial view in which I only had @Html.EditorForModel() which was using ObjectA as the model

Comment: @sparta223 tis is the reason why didn't bind, you needed an *empty model* with  property `ObjectA` and to use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ObjectA) `

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please include some code for the solution you are suggesting?