# getJson doesnt trigger controller ActionResult properly

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In Razor ASP I'm trying to get the Id of a database object as soon as it is registered. Here's the Json.

```
function Registrar() {
    var obj = { alcohol: $("#alcoholId").val(), tabaco: $("#tabacoId").val(), otros: $("#otrosId").val()};
    //alert($("#codigo").val());
    $.getJSON("/AntecedentesMvc/Registrar", obj, function (e) {
        if (e != "") {
            alert(e);
        }
        else {
            alert("se realizó un registro con exito");
            GetHabitoId();
        }
    });
}
function GetHabitoId() {
    $.getJSON("/AntecedentesMvc/GetHabitos", function (o) {
        $("#Hid").val();
    });
}
```

Registrar() works fine, it registers the object. and upon success (else) it should call the other funciton GetHabitoID().
It never goes to the controller. but If I edit the function Registrar() like this

```
function Registrar() {
    var obj = { alcohol: $("#alcoholId").val(), tabaco: $("#tabacoId").val(), otros: $("#otrosId").val()};
    //alert($("#codigo").val());
    $.getJSON("/AntecedentesMvc/Registrar", obj, function (e) {
        if (e != "") {
            alert(e);
        }
        else {
            alert("se realizó un registro con exito");
        }
        GetHabitoId();
    });
}

function GetHabitoId() {
    $.getJSON("/AntecedentesMvc/GetHabitos", function (o) {
        $("#Hid").val();
    });
}
```

GetHabitoId() does call the ActionResult. The issue is that it calls it before Registrar() does it's stuff. Returning null...

here are the controllers

```
Habitos objHabito=new Habitos();
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registrar(int alcohol, int tabaco, string otros)
{
    objHabito.Alcohol = alcohol;
    objHabito.Tabaco = tabaco;
    objHabito.Otros = otros;
    db.Habitos.Add(objHabito);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();  
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetHabitos ()
{
     var Habitoid = objHabito.Id_Habitos;
     return Json(Habitoid,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and if you need to see the button that calls the function

```
<input type="button" name="RegistrarH" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-default"onclick="Registrar();" data-dismiss="modal"/>
```

I'm really confused about this issue...

Comment: Try public JsonResult GetHabitos()

Comment: Why you're using `return View();` if you want to return back the POST result for client-side JS response?

Comment: Why are you using `$.getJSON` to call a `POST` action that returns a view that **isn't** JSON?

Comment: Does the `alert("se realizó un registro con exito");` trigger in else block?

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz now that you mention it. It doesn't trigger. May be it has something to do with the issue?

Comment: @mjwills I use the $.getJSON on Post to send the data to another controller, I'm using two controllers and I can't bind them through the asp conventional method. So I'm just using json to send the data to the controller and register the data to the database, on Post it doesn't really need to return anything.

Comment: @AzarShaikh Sadly it doesn't work, I just tried it but it still behaves as the ActionResult

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ - `Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request` You should not use that to call a `POST` endpoint. And you should not use that to return HTML (since it is designed to return JSON). You are basically trying to hammer in a nail with a chainsaw.

Comment: @mjwills Haha I'll try that. Also I hope you don't mind me using "You are basically trying to hammer in a nail with a chainsaw." as a phrase.
PS: Could you please give me a link to read about Http requests? I'd appreciate it, Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678187/jquery-ajax-send-json-and-return-html may be worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bad practices in this but to get it to work as intended I did the following.

```
function GetHabitoId() {
    $.getJSON("/AntecedentesMvc/GetHabitos", function (o) {
        $("#Hid").val(o);
    });
}
```

The issue was that val() was getting no parameters!